# OpenFaces 3 and IE6 (Button actions)

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, jsf-2, openfaces

I am using OpenFaces and have to be compatible with IE6. Up to now everything works more or less without problems.

However, I've run into a problem....

I've got a few buttons within a form. Save, Add, Export and Delete. Clicking on Export works fine with Firefox and IE8, exportToCsv() in the defined bean is invoked, so it must be a browser behaviour. Clicking on Export with IE6 invokes add() in the bean instead of exportToCsv().

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: still supporting IE6? You have my profound sympathies. I hope you're charging extra for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<o:commandButton>` component renders the `<button>` tag instead of `<input>` only if you specify the displayed button's content in between `<o:commandButton>` and `</o:commandButton>`. If you just need to display plain text, then you don't have to use this approach, and you can use the usual `value` attribute, which will result in rendering `<input>` tag instead of `<button>`, i.e. use:

```
<o:commandButton value="Submit"... />
```

instead of

```
<o:commandButton ...>Submit</o:commandButton>
```

The thing is that the latter form allows placing arbitrary HTML and thus requires the `<button>` tag.

Comment: I did specify content between the tags and do need them... However, do you know a workaround? How do I use O$.ajax.request getting a file back and open the file with window.open(...)? Do you have an example? Thank you.

Comment: A workaround is to switch the button to Ajax mode by specifying its render/execute attributes, if using Ajax is appropriate in your case. We'll also try to fix this in the component itself (just track the status of [OF-112](http://requests.openfaces.org/browse/OF-112))

Answer (score 1):

IE6 has bugs with the `<button>` element. It does support it, but it doesn't send the value correctly.

Solution 1: Use `<input type='button'>` instead.
This is probably the most obvious solution, but depending on your page design, it may be a problem because it doesn't support nested elements the way `<button>` does.

Solution 2: Use `<button>` but trigger the actions via Javascript (or more likely JQuery) rather than submitting the form directly, and use a technique such as having a hidden field that gets populated by JS according to which button is clicked, to ensure that the correct details get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitively a IE6 problem:

- http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/ie6-and-multiple-button-submit-elements/
- http://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE

Time to find a workaround...

- http://www.kopz.org/public/documents/css/multiple_buttons_ie_workaround.html

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround if using OpenFaces**

```
<o:outputLink styleClass="linkButton" ...>

.linkButton {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #565656;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px; /* Links */
}
```

Modified CSS from this source:

- http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element